# Transparent texture rendered as black

Tags: png, rendering, 3d, transparency, blender

I'm trying to render a scene with transparent png. The scene is actually imported from a `.obj` file (with another `.mtl` file), which should technically applies the transparency for me.

[image]

> ^ It does shows transparency in the viewport.

[image]

> ^However, in the rendered result it shows a black background instead of transparent background.

---

I have no idea why, and the `alpha` value is already at `1.000`. Any idea?

[image]

I'm using Blender 2.67, Blender Render. (not Cycles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a **transparent background**, in `Render` tab you need to change:

- Shading -> Alpha -> Transparent
- Output -> RGBA

[image: background transparency]

If you need a **transparent texture**, you must *activate transparency* in the material and lower Alpha value (Alpha=0 is fully transparent).

For example:

[image: material transparency]

Comment: You're welcome. If this method is suitable for you, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Sure.­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: So... I tested it and I set the `Alpha` to transparent, but it didn't work. The texture remains black.

Comment: Have you removed the background? Is the output set to RGBA?

Comment: Yes the output is set to `RGBA` and also I have set the alpha to `transparent`. I'm not sure about what do you mean by removed the background but those areas in the texture are transparent.

Comment: Background like a big plane under the scene (you can browse the objects using the scene tree, and perhaps you can select just the needed objects and move them in a new scene).

Comment: Oh I'm actually not trying to remove the background of the scene. I'm trying to make the transparent areas in my textures to show up as transparent in the render. Right now it is rendered with black replaced the transparent area.

Comment: Sorry, I'd misunderstand. If you need a transparent texture, you must activate transparency in the material and lower Alpha value (Alpha=0 is fully transparent). I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did enabled transparent and set Alpha to 0 but it's still showing as black in transparent area in the texture. [Here's a rendered image with another scene.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oi1Fz.jpg) The black background for the torches should be transparent, as well as the glass windows in the back. (somehow they show up as lightblue for some reason.)

Comment: A very odd render: each candle seems a composition of boxes textured with an imagemap without alpha channel. What kind of texture have you used? I suggest you this [tutorial](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/scene-view-alpha-transparency.php) and Blender manual ([here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Textures/Use_Alpha_for_Object_Transparency), [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Types/Image) and [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Applying_Image))

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 [This](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/BlenderAlpha/) tutorial too could be useful

Comment: The texture is a PNG with transparent background. If it is possible you can view the files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3iovkUln75aMDVsMUwzSUtTb28/edit?usp=sharing) and help me find where I did wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Alpha wasn't enabled for the torch texture, but this kind of texture map is difficult to apply to your object (it's too complex), in my opinion you need to use [UV Mapping](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping). I suggest you to ask to http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PaoloGibellini I know this is random and your answered this 4 years ago but I just had to say thank you, you saved my ass with this answer

Comment: @Jamiex304 StackExchange is always useful ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In the material tab go to "option" and uncheck "traceable" after that it should work and the transparency should be there .

Answer (score 0):

The "Alpha" you changed, is the Opacityvalue for the whole texture. If you turn this down everything would become transparent.

Comment: So how does this help?

Comment: I just wanted to say, what this "Alpha" Slider is for. And this doesn't change anything at your problem. Paolo already gave the correct anwswer. I was just adding some extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you use a lot of pngs you have to raise the transparent max bounces under render properties-Light paths-max bounces-transparency